How to Proxy Requests in Node.js Server to Avoid 429 Too Many Requests on External API?
I'm building a web application where multiple users frequently access data from an external API  via my server. To manage this traffic, I’m using a setup like this:
User requests data from my server (using a frontend React app).
My server (NestJs backend) forwards this request to the external API.
The response is returned to the user.
Here’s the challenge: the external API has a rate limit, so when multiple users (potentially thousands) access the data simultaneously, my server's IP gets hit with a 429 Too Many Requests response.

Why don't you let the client send the requests to the external API?

You could also re-try failed requests but if that works depends on the request throughput. If the request arrival rate of the service is higher than the request process rate (the rate limit of the external API) you are out of luck.
